# Is there an efficient way to keep the controls anchored to the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

Long story short, I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

The code I wrote to achieve this:

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Location = new Point(originalWindowPosX - Location.X, originalWindowPosY - Location.Y);
}
```

I just filled the window with a simple panel that contains multiple controls. When the window position changes, so does the panel position to make it look like it is pinned to the screen.

But it's not that efficient and consistent.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Yes, you can use [Form.DesktopLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.desktoplocation?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Zer0! But my question is regarding keeping form's controls fixed on the screen, I can't seem to succeed using DesktopLocation method. Maybe is something that I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding this to the Form's constructor: `var panelFixPos = PointToScreen(panel1.Location); this.Move += (s, e) => { panel1.Location = this.PointToClient(panelFixPos); };`. I suppose there will be some flickering. If you paint it is probably better.